# google play developer api not returning reviews

Tags: google-api-python-client, google-play-developer-api

i'm trying to get all the reviews of my app from the playstore using the google api python client and the play dev api.

Right now, if i print `response`, i get

`<googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object at 0x10302a990>`

when (i think) i should be getting all the reviews of my app. Not sure if my code is wrong, or I just didn't get the permissions correctly.

Thanks!

Code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'playcreds.json'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

playstore = googleapiclient.discovery.build('androidpublisher','v2', credentials=credentials)

response = playstore.reviews()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reviews()` is just the service endpoint. Look at the similar samples for listing APKs [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v2/python/basic_list_apks.py).

Instead, you probably want to try something like `playstore.reviews().list(...)` with the appropriate parameters from [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/reviews/list).

Comment: The review().list link is 404. The new one is here
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/reviews/list